# Evaluate: $\int \frac{t^5-t^3}{t^{10}-1}\, dt. $

Tags: indefinite-integrals

None of my attempts (such as letting $x=t^5$ or splitting up the integrand into two parts etc.) succeeded. Basically I couldn't find a useful thing on manipulating the given integrand. Please give me some hints.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried Partial Fraction Decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#:~:text=In%20algebra%2C%20the%20partial%20fraction,or%20several%20fractions%20with%20a?

Comment: Actually I did try it but something horrible was coming so didn't proceed further.

Comment: As you can see in Wolfran I imagine this is difficult to do, you're right...

Comment: It is a pretty nasty indefinite integral. You sure there were no bounds given?

Answer (score 1):

With $u=t^2$ this is $\tfrac12\int\frac{u(u-1)\,\mathrm{d}u}{u^5-1}=\tfrac12\int\frac{u\,\mathrm{d}u}{u^4+u^3+u^2+u+1}$. You can factorize the quartic denominator into two real quadratics, using fifth roots of unity. Then you can proceed with partial fractions. (You might not like [the result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2F2%29*u%2F%28u%5E4%2Bu%5E3%2Bu%5E2%2Bu%2B1%29) if you don't remove the explicit role of complex numbers early. See @AlexeyBurdin's comment.)

Comment: Indeed, $u^4+u^3+u^2+u+1=\left(u^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}u+1\right)\left(u^2+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}u+1\right)$

Comment: Actually I tried this approach too but after obtaining the form of the denominator(that Alexey Burdin has mentioned) I restrained myself and posted it here hoping that there could be some elite way to handle it. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \frac{t^5-t^3}{t^{10}-1}\, dt = \int \frac{t^4-t^2}{t^{10}-1} \, \big( t\, dt\big)
$$
Why would I do what you see above? Note that $t$ is a constant multiple of the derivative of $t^2,$ and doing what appears above leaves you with a function of $t^2$ in the fraction. In other words, this substitution is indicated:
\begin{align}
& u = t^2 \\
& du = 2t\, dt \\
& du/2 = t\,dt
\end{align}
So the integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{u^2 -u}{u^5 -1} \cdot \frac{du} 2
$$
Now to use a partial fraction decomopsition you need to factor $u^5-1.$ Since $u^5-1=0$ when $u=1,$ you have $u-1$ as a factor, thus:
$$
u^5-1= (u-1)(u^4+u^3+u^2+1)
$$
However, this leaves the problem of how to factor that 4th-degree polynomial. There's a formula for factoring 4th-degree polynomials, but it's cumbersome, and what most mathematicians know about it is where to look it up in a book. But in this case, the way to do this is to look at the other solutions of $u^5-1=0$ besides $u=1.$

We need $u^5 = 1.$ Necessarily this means $|u|=1,$ so the values of $u$ that we seek must be on the circle centered at $0$ with radius $1.$ That means they are of the form $\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha.$ Now recall that
$$
\big( \cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha\big)^5 = \cos(5\alpha) + i \sin(5\alpha).
$$
This is equal to $1$ only if $\cos(5\alpha)=1$ and $\sin(5\alpha)=0.$
So we need $\alpha$ to be one-fifth of an integer multiple of $360^\circ.$ Thus $\alpha\in\{0^\circ,\pm72^\circ, \pm144^\circ\}$ and we've already found the case $\alpha=0^\circ$ with $u=1.$ Looking at $\pm72^\circ,$ we have
\begin{align}
& \Big( x - \big(\cos72^\circ+i\sin72^\circ\big) \Big) \Big( x - \big( \cos72^\circ - i\sin72^\circ \big) \Big) \\
& \text{complex-conjugate pairs, so the imaginary parts cancel out} \\[10pt]
= {} & x^2 - 2x\cos72^\circ + 1.
\end{align}
And similarly with $144^\circ.$ So we get:
$$
u^5-1 = (u-1) (x^2 - 2x\cos72^\circ + 1) (x^2 - 2x\cos144^\circ + 1)
$$
After that, use partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

And I'll finish the thing. $I=\int\frac{t^5-t^3}{t^{10}-1}\,\mathrm{d}t$
Let $u=t^2,du=2t\,dt$, by [J.G.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3709904)
$$I=\frac12\int\frac{u\,\mathrm{d}u}{u^4+u^3+u^2+u+1}$$
Using $$u^4+u^3+u^2+u+1=\left(u^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}u+1\right)
\left(u^2+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}u+1\right)$$ both parenthesis have no real roots, so we will have to boil that down to $\int\frac{ax+b}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$ for some $x$ after partial decomposition. So complete the squares:
$$\left(u^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}u+1\right)
\left(u^2+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}u+1\right)=\\
\left(\left(\frac{4u+1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2+\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}\right)
\left(\left(\frac{-4u-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2+\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}\right)$$
As we see $4u+1$ shows up in both cases, let $4u+1=x$, $u=\frac{x-1}{4}$, $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{d}x$ and
[$$I=8\int\frac{x-1}{x^4 + 10 x^2 + 40 x + 205}\mathrm{d}x$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2*u*1%2F4%2F%28u%5E4%2Bu%5E3%2Bu%5E2%2Bu%2B1%29+where+u%3D%28x-1%29%2F4)
$$=8\int\frac{x-1}{\left((x - \sqrt{5})^2 + 2\sqrt{5} + 10\right)
\left((x + \sqrt{5})^2 - 2\sqrt{5} + 10\right)}\mathrm{d}x$$
and the partial fraction decomposition is (details are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x+-+sqrt%285%29%29%5E2+%2B+2*sqrt%285%29+%2B+10%29*%28a*%28x+-+sqrt%285%29%29%2Bb%29%2B%28%28x+%2B+sqrt%285%29%29%5E2+-+2*sqrt%285%29+%2B+10%29*%28c*%28x+%2B+sqrt%285%29%29%2Bd%29) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bc%3D0%2C+-3*sqrt%285%29*a%2Bb%2B3*sqrt%285%29*c%2Bd%3D0%2C+2*sqrt%285%29*a%2B25*a-2*sqrt%285%29*b-2*sqrt%285%29*c%2B25*c%2B2*sqrt%285%29*d%3D1%2C+-15*sqrt%285%29*a-10*a%2B2*sqrt%285%29*b%2B15*b%2B15*sqrt%285%29*c-10*c-2*sqrt%285%29*d%2B15*d%3D-1))$$
\frac{x-1}{x^4 + 10 x^2 + 40 x + 205}=
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{(x - \sqrt{5})^2 + 2\sqrt{5} + 10}-\frac{1}{(x + \sqrt{5})^2 - 2\sqrt{5} + 10}\right)$$
$$I=\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\right)}{\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\right)^2+1}-
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{-2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\right)}{\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{-2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\right)^2+1}
\right)$$
$$=\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\arctan\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\right)-
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\arctan\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{-2\sqrt{5} + 10}}\right)
\right)+C$$
where $x=4t^2+1$.